# SQL Server Generate Insert Script based on query

Tags: sql-server, ssms

We have two databases with almost identical schemas on a MS SQL Server 2017.
I need to reimport data to an old database from a new database, except the values that are in the old database.

To show the values that are not in the old database I used the following query:

```
SELECT id FROM DB1.Table1
EXCEPT
SELECT id FROM DB2.Table1);
```

How can I generate an insert script for differential data?

EDIT: Preceeding the statement with INSERT is no option, I need the full Script backup purposes and to run it on remote servers.

Comment: Use `insert(...) select ... where id not in(select id from ...)`.

Comment: What's wrong with preceeding the statement with an `INSERT INTO`...?

Comment: I want to see the full script for backup purposes.

Comment: Do you want to do this once off or many times? There's no easy way to do this. If you want a one off script, insert that into a temp table then extract insert statements from the temp table

Comment: Does it have to be a script? Can you bcp queryout the result of the select-except-select statement to a file and then bulkinsert that file on the required servers?

Comment: You said you wanted a script - but using TSQL to generate a script is generally impossible for those without advanced tsql skills. So what EXACTLY is your goal? Is this as simple as generating an export file (perhaps as CSV) containing a set of rows that you want to then import to other databases?